# How do I combine two lists into a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of the same length:

`[1,2,3,4]` and `[a,b,c,d]`

I want to create a dictionary where I have `{1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}`

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: the downside of stackoverflow is that there is even less incentive to rtfm: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
dict(zip([1,2,3,4], [a,b,c,d]))
```

If the lists are big you should use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

If you have more keys than values, and you want to fill in values for the extra keys, you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Here, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are variables -- it will work fine (so long as they are defined), but you probably meant `['a','b','c','d']` if you want them as strings.

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) takes the first item from each iterable and makes a tuple, then the second item from each, etc. etc.

[`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can take an iterable of iterables, where each inner iterable has two items -- it then uses the first as the key and the second as the value for each item.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to `izip_longest`, I needed exactly this.

Comment: izip() is removed in Python3 , simply use zip()

Comment: This is how an answer on stack should be! A clear example on top you can easily copy, a brief description to point to the right direction, links to learn more and it's short, you have the whole answer in one page.

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> dict(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

If they are not the same size, `zip` will truncate the longer one.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict reference

Answer (score 7):

```
dict(zip([1,2,3,4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Answer (score 6):

If there are duplicate keys in the first list that map to different values in the second list, like a 1-to-many relationship, but you need the values to be combined or added or something instead of updating, you can do this:

```
i = iter(["a", "a", "b", "c", "b"])
j = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
k = list(zip(i, j))
for (x,y) in k:
    if x in d:
        d[x] = d[x] + y #or whatever your function needs to be to combine them
    else:
        d[x] = y
```

In that example, `d == {'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'b': 8}`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about best (simplest? fastest? most readable?), but one way would be:

```
dict(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [a, b, c, d]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing to create a dictionary of three lists (latitude, longitude, and a value), with the following doing the trick:

```
> lat = [45.3,56.2,23.4,60.4]
> lon = [134.6,128.7,111.9,75.8]
> val = [3,6,2,5]
> dict(zip(zip(lat,lon),val))
{(56.2, 128.7): 6, (60.4, 75.8): 5, (23.4, 111.9): 2, (45.3, 134.6): 3}
```

or similar to the above examples:

```
> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
> list2 = [1,2,3,4]
> list3 = ['a','b','c','d']
> dict(zip(zip(list1,list2),list3))
{(3, 3): 'c', (4, 4): 'd', (1, 1): 'a', (2, 2): 'b'}
```

**Note:** Dictionaries are "orderless", but if you would like to view it as "sorted", refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key) question if you'd like to sort by key, or [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) question if you'd like to sort by value.