# Merge two lists,one as keys, one as values, into a dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any **build-in** function in Python that merges two lists into a dict? Like:

```
combined_dict = {}

keys = ["key1","key2","key3"] 

values = ["val1","val2","val3"]

for k,v in zip(keys,values):
    combined_dict[k] = v
```

Where:

`keys` acts as the list that contains the keys.

`values` acts as the list that contains the values

There is a function called [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) that achieves this effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like this should work, though I guess it's not *one* single function:

```
dict(zip(["key1","key2","key3"], ["val1","val2","val3"]))
```

from here: [How do I combine two lists into a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271385/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Also `{k:v for k,v in zip(['k1','k2'],['v1','v2'])}`

Comment: @burhankhalid dict is better for compatibility reasons.