# merge two lists into dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge two lists to dict:

```
l1 = [1, 3, 6, 0, 1, 1]
l2 = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo2', 'bar1']
```

I'd like to get:

```
list = [{"foo1": 1},
             {"foo2": 3},
             {"foo1": 6},
             {"foo2": 0},
             {"foo2": 1},
             {"bar1": 1},]
```

trying to use zip but get an error :"<zip object at 0x000>"

Comment: Well, It's not an error, It's just a string representation of zip object,

Comment: `[{l2_item:l1_item} for l1_item,l2_item in zip(l1,l2)]` does this produce what you want?

Comment: Besides, you didn't show your code for the zip.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271385/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: @TedBrownlow exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
l1 = [1, 3, 6, 0, 1, 1]
l2 = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo2', 'bar1']

data = [{k: v} for k, v in zip(l2, l1)]

print(data)
```

Output:

```py
[{'foo1': 1}, {'foo2': 3}, {'foo1': 6}, {'foo2': 0}, {'foo2': 1}, {'bar1': 1}]
```

I wouldn't consider this an ideal data structure though, unless you have a lot more data in the individual dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [@Tenacious B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65572803/21945) achieves what you requested.

You might, however, be better with a dictionary of lists. The keys would be items from `l2` and values would be a *list* containing the corresponding values from `l1`. A [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) makes this easy:

```
l1 = [1, 3, 6, 0, 1, 1]
l2 = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo2', 'bar1']

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(l2, l1):
    d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(, {'foo1': [1, 6], 'foo2': [3, 0, 1], 'bar1': [1]})
```

Now you can access the data by key:

```
>>> d['foo2']
[3, 0, 1]
>>> d['foo1']
[1, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `<zip object at 0x0000021A9C9F71C0>` is not an error, you just haven't execute the code yet. It is stored in a zip object which is waiting for execution.